# Zlib in Ruby to uncompress .gz

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a .gz file that contains an XML document. Does anyone know how to use Zlib properly? So far, I have the following code:

```
require 'zlib'
Zlib::GzipReader.open('PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1015.xml.gz') { |gz|
    g = File.new("PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1015.xml", "w")
      g.write(gz)
      g.close()
}
```

But this creates a blank .xml document. Does anyone know how I can properly do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Zlib::GzipReader` works like most `IO`-like classes do in Ruby. You have an `open` call, and when you pass a block to it, the block will receive the `IO`-like object. Think of it is convenient way of doing something with a file or resource for the duration of the block.

But that means that in your example `gz` is an `IO`-like object, and not actually the contents of the gzip file, as you expect. You still need to `read` from it to get to that. The simplest fix would then be:

```
g.write(gz.read)
```

Note that this will read the entire contents of the **uncompressed** gzip into memory.

If all you're really doing is copying from one file to another, you can use the more efficient `IO.copy_stream` method. Your example might then look like:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.open('PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1015.xml.gz') do | input_stream |
  File.open("PRIDE_Exp_Complete_Ac_1015.xml", "w") do |output_stream|
    IO.copy_stream(input_stream, output_stream)
  end
end
```

Behind the scenes, this will try to use the `sendfile` syscall available in some specific situations on Linux. Otherwise, it will do the copying in fast C code 16KB blocks at a time. This I learned from the Ruby 1.9.1 source code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Ruby one-liner ( cd .git/ first and identify path to any object ):

```
ruby -rzlib -e 'print Zlib::Inflate.new.inflate(STDIN.read)' < ./74/c757240ec596063af8cd273ebd9f67073e1208
```