# Open3.popen3 function to open bz, gz, and txt files errors with 'No such file or directory' or 'not opened for reading'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip, bzip

I'm trying to write a utility function that will open three different types of files: .bz2, .gz, and .txt.  I can't just use `File.read` because it gives me garbage back for the compressed files.  I'm trying to use `Open3.popen3` so that I can give it a different command, but I'm getting a 'no such file or directory' error with the following code:

```
def file_info(file)
  cmd = ''
  if file.match("bz2") then
    cmd = "bzcat #{file}"# | head -20"
  elsif file.match("gz") then
    cmd = "gunzip -c #{file}"
  else
    cmd = "cat #{file}"
  end

  puts "opening file #{file}"
  Open3.popen3("#{cmd}", "r+") { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    puts "stdin #{stdin.inspect}"
    stdin.read {|line|
      puts "line is #{line}"
      if line.match('^#') then
      else
        break
      end
    }
  }
end


> No such file or directory - cat /tmp/test.txt
```

The file does exist.  I've tried using `cmd` instead of `#{cmd}` with the same results in the `popen3 cmd`.

I decided to hardcode it to do the txt file as follows:

```
def file_info(file)
  puts "opening file #{file}"
  Open3.popen3("cat", file, "r+") { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    puts "stdin #{stdin.inspect}"
    stdin.read {|line|
      puts "line is #{line}"
      if line.match('^#') then
      else
        break
      end
    }
  }
end
```

This gives me back:

```
stdin #<IO:fd 6>
not opened for reading
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I do:

```
Open3.popen3("cat",file) { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  puts "stdout is #{stdout.inspect}"
  stdout.read {|line|
    puts "line is #{line}"
    if line.match('^#') then
      puts "found line #{line}"
    else
      break
    end
  }
}
```

I get no errors and the STDOUT line is printed, but neither line statement prints out anything.

After trying several different things, the solution I came up with was:

```
cmd = Array.new
if file.match(/\.bz2\z/) then
  cmd = [ 'bzcat', file ]
elsif file.match(/\.gz\z/) then
  cmd = [ 'gunzip', '-c', file ]
else
  cmd = [ 'cat', file ]
end

Open3.popen3(*cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  puts "stdout is #{stdout}"
  stdout.each do |line|
    if line.match('^#') then
      puts "line is #{line}"
    else
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `r+` flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) (which is rather confusingly written):

> **popen3(*cmd, &block)**
> [...]
> So a commandline string and list of argument strings can be accepted as follows.
>
> ```
> Open3.popen3("echo a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
> Open3.popen3("echo", "a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
> Open3.popen3(["echo", "argv0"], "a") {|i, o, e, t| ... }
> ```

So when you do this:

```
Open3.popen3("cat /tmp/test.txt", "r+")
```

`popen3` thinks that the command name is `cat /tmp/test.txt` and `r+` is an argument to that command, hence the specific error that you're seeing:

> No such file or directory - cat /tmp/test.txt

There's no need for the usual mode flags (`"r+"`) with `Open3.popen3` since it will separate handles for reading, writing, and errors; and, as you've seen, trying to supply the mode string just causes bugs and confusion.

The second case:

```
Open3.popen3("cat", file, "r+") { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.each {|line|
    #...
```

Doesn't work because `stdin` is the command's standard input and that's what you would *write to* not *read from*, you'd want to `stdout.read` instead.

You should be building your commands as arrays and your `match` calls should be a little stricter:

```
if file.match(/\.bz2\z/) then
  cmd = [ 'bzcat', file ]
elsif file.match(/\.gz\z/) then
  cmd = [ 'gunzip', '-c', file ]
else
  cmd = [ 'cat', file ]
end
```

and then splat them:

```
Open3.popen3(*cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  #...
end
```

Not only does this work but it will save you from funny filenames.

You could also avoid a useless use of `cat` (which someone will probably complain about) by skipping the `Open3.popen3` for the non-compressed cases and using `File.open` instead. You might also want to consider checking the file's bytes to see what it contains rather than relying on the extension (or use [ruby-filemagic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901660/479863) to check for you).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I've updated my question with the results of testing this (because I evidently can't do code in a comment).

Comment: @Denise: Sorry about that, my brain says one thing but sometimes my fingers type something else.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use [bzip2-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby) and [GzipReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169373/zlib-in-ruby-to-uncompress-gz) for reading corresponding files. Opening a separate process for that is too expensive, complex and fragile.

Comment: Doesn't calling "reader = Bzip2::Reader.new File.open('file')" create a new process anyway?  What's the difference if so?

Comment: It does not create a new process.