# Unzipping a file (.gz) in JRuby using Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gzip, jruby, unzip

Does anyone know of a gem that is compatible with JRuby 1.6.5 that can extract the files from a .gz zip file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `Zlib` in my JRuby app. It is a standard Ruby library. 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html

In Rails you can also use `ActiveSupport::Gzip` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Gzip.html

Here are examples how to unzip a file: [Zlib in Ruby to uncompress .gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169373/zlib-in-ruby-to-uncompress-gz)